# PowerApps Mail.SendMailV3 throws datatype Error

Tags: types, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Following code is written inside a Button in a PowerApps Canvas App:

```
Mail.SendEmailV3(GalleryUserSelector_1.Selected.Mail;EmailSubjectInput_1.Text;EmailBodyInput_1.Text;false)
```

it throws this error

Translated to English:
"The untyped object argument for the Boolean function has an incorrect type. Expected: Boolean, Actually: object."

Original in German:
"Das nicht typisierte Objektargument für die Funktion "Boolean" weisst einen fehlerhaften Typ auf. Erwartet: Boolean, Tatsächlich: object."

I have tried casting the "false" to a boolean like such "Boolean(false)" but this did not change anything. All the Field Calls return Text values. What is the issue with my code?

Edit: If the fourth Parameter is removed following error appears:
[image]

Translated: Invalid number of arguments. Received 3, expected: 4-5.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should drop the last/fourth parameter "true" as this isn't needed.
See SendEmailV3 documentation for the list of parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sendmail/#send-an-email-notification-(v3)

Comment: If the fourth parameter is dropped its throws an invalid number of argument error

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you use the `OnSelect` of a button?

`Mail.SendMailV3` method expects 4 arguments:

1. `to` string
2. `subject` string
3. `text` string
4. `ishtml` boolean

[image: sendmailv3]

```
Mail.SendEmailV3("to@mail.domain","subject","<p>hello</p>",true)
```

Check out this great article: [Send An Email Notification Using Mail Connector In PowerApps](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-an-email-notification-using-mail-connector-in-powerapps/)

Note that in English the separator is a `comma` but it could different in other language. It's a good practice to develop with a browser in English, so copy/paste example or share screenshots of error is easier